# Can i use google text to speech app for comercial use?

Tags: android, google-play, google-code

i have taken AOSP code and build for my system? AOSP does not provide apk for google text to speech apk.

Now i want to build application which supports tts using google text to speech engine so i have installed google text to speech apk from external source and made application which uses google tts engine and it is working fine.

I am not sure weather we can use google text to speech for commercial use? is there any legal terms and condition to use this?

I am not able to find any documentation of google text to speech .

Comment: Is Google text-to-speech open source? If not, it does not really belong here. To ask about out licensing of a Google commercial product then you must contact Google of course.

Comment: Although this site is happy to help interpret free licences, we aren't here to do the research about what licence applies in the first place.  If you have evidence that this service is available under a specific licence, please edit that into your question; otherwise, it seems likely this is a question about using a proprietary web service in a proprietary product, and that is very much off-topic for this site.

Comment: Also what do you mean by commercial use. **ALL** Open Source / Free Software licences allow commercial use. What they do not all allow is to close it off / to make it non-free (that is to take away the freedoms). However some do allow this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be about free software within the definition of the site.

Answer (score 2):

The [API](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python) (and only the API) is under the Apache v2 License, so you can use that under its terms which includes commercial usage; that doesn't make google's TTS open-source though.

Actual access to the API and services requires agreement to further terms from google which are described in the documentation and when signing up for / signing-in to a google account.